# Centering child of a `Container` without changing container size

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I was working on my custom button which uses `InkWell` and `Container` to animate it when tapped

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Button extends StatefulWidget {
  final VoidCallback onPressed;
  final Widget child;
  final double minWidth;
  final bool disabled;
  final bool bordered;
  final Color fillColor;
  final bool elevated;

  const Button({
    required this.child,
    required this.onPressed,
    this.minWidth = 180,
    this.disabled = false,
    this.bordered = false,
    this.fillColor = Colors.white,
    this.elevated = true,
  });

  @override
  _ButtonState createState() => _ButtonState();
}

class _ButtonState extends State<Button> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _animationController;
  late Animation<double> _scaleAnimation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController = AnimationController(
        vsync: this, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 150));

    _scaleAnimation = Tween<double>(begin: 1.0, end: 0.97).animate(
        CurvedAnimation(parent: _animationController, curve: Curves.easeInOut));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _scaleAnimation,
      builder: (context, child) {
        return Transform.scale(scale: _scaleAnimation.value, child: child);
      },
      child: InkWell(
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            boxShadow: widget.elevated
                ? [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.05),
                      blurRadius: 20,
                    )
                  ]
                : [],
            color: widget.fillColor,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
              16.0,
            ),
            border: Border.all(
              width: 1.0,
              color: Colors.grey.shade300,
            ),
          ),
          child: widget.child,
        ),
        onHighlightChanged: (bool pressed) {
          if (pressed)
            _animationController.forward();
          else
            _animationController.reverse(from: _animationController.value);
        },
        highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
        splashColor: Colors.transparent,
        onTap: widget.disabled ? null : widget.onPressed,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So right now the problem is occurring when pass it a `Text` widget. It aligns to the left of the container.

[image: a picture showing button with left aligned text]

I tried wrapping `widget.child` with a `Align` widget

```dart
...
child: Align(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    child: widget.child,
),
```

It works fine aligns the `ADD` text to the center.

[image: A button with text aligned to the center]

But when I use this button in place of `floatingActionButton` it expands to cover the whole screen.

[image: A FAB expanded to cover the whole screen]

I want fab something like this

[image]

Comment: can you show how you are using the button widget inplace of floatingaction button

Answer (score 0):

You can just put the widget in a row with minimum mainAxisSize and that should solve it.

```
floatingActionButton: Button(
  minWidth: 200,
  child: Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
     children: [
     Icon(Icons.add),
     SizedBox(width: 8),
     Text("TIME SLOT")
     ]
  ),
  onPressed: () {}));
```

Heres the output from the dartpad

[image]